# aws ec2 ls command is showing the user@ip:directory/folder on the last line - How can I remove this from my ls output?

Tags: linux, ls, aws, amazon-ec2

When I perform an ls command in my aws ec2 server, I am getting the correct list of files which I need, but for some reason the `user@ip:directory/folder` is showing on the last line of my results? Is there any way to remove this?

I am parsing some dates from a list of files to process later, but this `user@ip:directory/folder` is showing up in the list and causing issues.

Example:
My directory is `documents/files`
within files there are

```
20191214.txt
20191215.txt
20191216.txt
```

I run the command `aws s3 ls documents/files`

and the result is

```
20191214.txt
20191215.txt
20191216.txt
user@ip:documents/files
```

Is there any way to remove `user@ip:documents/files` from my list of results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
aws ec2 ls | sed 's@.*:.*/.*@@'
```

or if it's STDERR:

```
aws ec2 ls 2> >(grep -v'*:.*/.*')
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilles but it didn't work, i got the same output

Comment: Can you try the 2nth solution from my edited post ?

Comment: Tried it and still the output returns this line at the end: user@ip-##-###-##-###:/home/user/dir1/dir2... I'm not sure if this is because its aws ec2 default or what...

Comment: Maybe an alternative would be to grep from the ls output the list of dates i need? Do you know how I may do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore it with `aws s3 ls documents/files | head -n -1`, which will return all but the last line of the results. From the `head` man page:

> head [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
>
> -n, --lines=[-]K
>
> print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file